# Is there a direct combinatorial interpretation of this (seemingly coincidental) result?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

The original problem is as follows:

> Find the probability $p$ that in a bridge game the players North, East, South, West have $a, b, c, d$ spades, respectively (which implies $a+b+c+d=13$).

And after simple counting, you'll get the answer, which can be rewritten as:
$$p=\frac{\binom{13}{a}\,\binom{13}{b}\,\binom{13}{c}\,\binom{13}{d}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

And it seems like this result can be directly obtained by interpreting the numerator and denominator respectively, but I'm stuck with how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think your answer is correct. Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1416902/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Actually they are the same, and you can rewrite it as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out:

> Suppose that there are 52 positions in a row where you can put 13 spades into different positions there. So you'll have $\binom{52}{13}$ choices in total. And now you want there to be $a$ spades in the first 13 positions, $b$ spades in the second 13 positions, $c$ spades in the third 13 positions, and $d$ spades in the fourth 13 positions, where $a+b+c+d=13$. So in this case you'll have $\binom{13}{a}\,\binom{13}{b}\,\binom{13}{c}\,\binom{13}{d}$ choices in total. Thus the result follows.

It's worth mentioning that in the above interpretation actually all cards are split into only two kinds, one kind is *spades*, and the other one is *non-spades*. And you can treat all *spades* as the same and all *non-spades* as the same.

To some extent, this seemingly simple interpretation can really provide some insights into this kind of problems.

Comment: This is a really nice way to think about this problem - very natural and simple, yet not at all obvious (to me, at least).

Comment: This is quite a bit simpler than the solution linked to in the comments. (I changed the wording slightly, but feel free to change it back if you prefer.)